# Convert a JSON Object to Comma Sepearted values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON OBJECT

```
{"data":{"source1":"source1val","source2":"source2val"}}
```

which i want to convert into

```
data : source1val, source2val.
```

Comment: JSON is not a flat structure like CSV! What do you want? One **guess** could be: All values of the properties of the data-object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

---

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var input = {
  "data": {
    "source1": "source1val",
    "source2": "source2val"
  }
};
var output = Object.keys(input.data).map(function(k) {
  return input.data[k];
}).join(',');
console.log(output); //manipulated object
console.log(input); //Original object
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But this creates an array, not a comma-separated string.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I was expecting this :P Thanks for highlighting it :)

Comment: Worked via this idea.. Thankyou..!! @rayon
Can you pls tell me how to reconvert it back to json object

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to reconvert it back to json object @RayonDabre

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = {
  "data": {
    "source1": "source1val",
    "source2": "source2val"
  }
};
var output = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < input.data.length; i++) { 
    output.push(input.data[i]);
}
```